# How can USB list become unaccessible to non root users at some point?

Tags: raspberry-pi, udev, lsusb

I'm using a Raspberry Pi4 device. We plug a USB HUB connected to 2 USB devices (a Fluigent pressure controller and a FTDI-based home made board controller).

After booting, I run `lsusb`, it lists many devices (hubs, mouse, keyboard...). Then I plug my USB HUB. Now when I run `lsusb`, it only lists a single device "Linux foundation 2.0 root hub", all other devices disappeared.

If I run `sudo lsusb`, the devices are all visible.

What can lead to this? Non-root users should have access to USB enumeration.

**Note:** I originally hit the problem by deploying some C++ code using library [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp) and got "libudev error -13" reported by `libusbp`. Then I found out that using `sudo` works and saw that `lsusb` reproduces the problem outside my progrem. Maybe this `-13` error code can help.

Comment: That is very surprising. Maybe some broken udev rule?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Is this something I did wrong at some point? I just installed Raspberry Pi OS and played with it...

Comment: probably not, unless you know you played with udev rules…

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Just realized I ran this script recommanded by Fluigent team: https://github.com/Fluigent/fgt-SDK/blob/master/linux-udev.sh.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Could that be the cause? How can I undo this script operations to retry?

Comment: try moving /etc/udev/rules.d/99-fluigent.rules to a backup location, rebooting, and see whether things still happen

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, just tested that, does not make any difference...

Comment: well, that's kind of good news :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller good news but does not fix the issue...:-(